# Subtract or add values from sum depending on the another column value

Tags: java, mysql, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I would like to sum or subtract values (quantity) based on condition that another column value (type). In vanilla sql will be like so:

```
sum( if(`type` = 1, -1, 1) * `quantity` )
```

How can i achieve this using `querydsl 4`. This is what i have so far

```
collectionTransaction.quantity.sum()
```

What i cannot figure out is to implement the logic in it.

Comment: Isn’t `CASE` more vanilla than `IF` In Sql? Anyway I would look into using the support for the [Case](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/#d0e2105) statement in QueryDsl

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Joakim Danielson's reference i managed to get it right. This is how i got it right:

```
new CaseBuilder() 
      .when(collectionTransaction.collectionType.eq(1))
      .then(collectionTransaction.quantity.sum())
      .otherwise(collectionTransaction.quantity.negate().sum()),
```

which translated to following sql statement:

```
case 
  when collection0_.collection_transaction_type=1 then sum(collection0_.quantity) 
  else sum(-collection0_.quantity) 
end as col_1_0_,
```